# What is the most efficient matrix representation in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, vlfeat

I hope that this question is not OT.

I'm implementing a [VLAD](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/encodings.html) encoder using the [VLFeat implementation](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/vlad.html) and [SIFT](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html) descriptors from different implementations to compare them (OpenCV, VLFeat, [OpenSIFT](https://robwhess.github.io/opensift/)).

This is supposed to be an high performance application in C++ (I know that SIFT is very inefficient, I'm implementing a parallel version of it).

Now, VLAD wants as input the pointer to a set of contiguous descriptors (math vectors). The point is that usually this SIFT descriptors are represented as a matrix, so it's easier to manage them.

So supposing that we have a matrix of 3 descriptors in 3 dimensions (I'm using these numbers for sake of simplicity, actually it's thousands of descriptors in 128 dimensions):

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I need to do feed [`vl_vlad_encode`](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/vlad_8c.html#a6ee2926e14d4a76e9d99ba128bfe5a80) with the pointer to:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

An straightforward solution is saving descriptors in a `cv::Mat m` object and then pass `m.data` to `vl_vlad_encode`.

However I don't know if `cv::Mat` is an efficient matrix representation. For example, [`Eigen::Matrix`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html) is an alternative (I think it's easy to obtain the representation above using this object), but I don't know which implementation is faster/more efficient or if there is any other reason because I should prefer one instead of the other.

Another possible alternative is using `std::vector<std::vector<float>> v`, but I don't know if using `v.data()` I would obtain the representation above instead of:
`1 2 3 *something* 4 5 6 *something* 7 8 9`

Obviously `*something*` would mess up `vl_vlad_encode`.

Any other suggestion is more than welcome!

Comment: `float [9]`? Agree on a column- or row-major convention and then you can layout everything contiguously one column or one row after the other.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman care to explain the difference between float[9] and float[3][3]?  They're both contiguous and the column/row convention is changeable for both.

Comment: I forgot to say that the matrix dimension is decided at runtime, so using `std::vector<float> v` and then `v.resize(dim)` (or `v.reserve(dim)`) could be a better solution, where `dim=9` in this case.

Comment: Unless you do some weird stuff (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33674655/5008845) for details), data in a `Mat` are continuous. You can think of a `Mat` as a lightweight wrapper over a `float*` (or other types) that allows easier access to the data. So it's as efficient as a pointer, but with a few nice-to-have abstractions.

Comment: This is what I wanted to hear @Miki, thanks so much. It would be much easier to use `Mat` for SIFT and to write/read it to file (using xml and yaml) files. So you say that there is no loss in time/memory performances, but it's easier to manage them, right?

Comment: Correct. You can also improve write/read to file performance using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32357875/5008845). Using xml or yaml can be too slow. if you don't need human-readable files, you can save in binary form with the functions in the link

Comment: @Miki absolutely better, I was looking for a binary representation of `Mat`. If you'll post it as an answer and no one will come up with a better solution I will chose it!

Comment: test if mat is continuous and if it isn't: use mat.clone() to create a continuous copy of your mat. How big are your matrices? Will it have any real influence on processing speed if you just copy them to a vector of floats (not vector of vector of float!)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you do some weird stuff (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33674655/5008845) for details), data in a `Mat` are guaranteed to be continuous. You can think of a `Mat` as a lightweight wrapper over a `float*` (or other types) that allows easier access to the data. So it's as efficient as a pointer, but with a few nice-to-have abstractions.

If you need to efficiently load/save from/to file, you can save the `Mat` in binary format using [`matread` and `matwrite`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357875/5008845).

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<std::vector<float>> v` is not going to perform very well without some effort, since the memory will not be contiguous.

Once you have your memory contiguous, be it float[], float[][] or std::array/vector, how well it will perform will depend on how you iterate over your matrix.  If it's random access, then it makes little difference; if you're iterating all columns per for then it's better to have your data grouped by column rather than row.