# Copying OpenCV mat to a known address with memcpy

Tags: c++, opencv, memcpy

I'm very new at C++ and I'm trying to create a `DLL` which uses OpenCV library.

My `DLL` gets a raw image from other application and creates a `MAT` from the application's memory buffer. I send the buffer's address, which has a raw image, to the `DLL` and get raw image to OpenCV. This part works.
But after processing image with OpenCV, I can't write raw image to same memory address.

This is the code snippet that I've tried:

```
fn_export double createImage(char* address  double width, double height) {
  
  unsigned char* pBuffer = (unsigned char*)address;
  memcpy(&pBuffer,&address, sizeof(pBuffer));
  cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(height,width, CV_8UC4, pBuffer);
  cv::imshow("Original", img);

  memcpy(&address, &img.data[0], sizeof(address));

  return 1;
}
```

`char* address` is memory address from my application. Other application's buffer doesn't change this way. Anybody has any advice about this situation?

Comment: In memcpy() when you take sizeof(address), this is incorrect because this is just copying the pointer not the actual data at the location where the pointer points to. Also &address[0] and &address are the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, you are right. I realized that some definitions in my code are unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I solved this issue ;

```
    Mat img = Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, address);
cv::imshow("Image from GM", img);
// same image copy to buffer back;
memcpy(&address[0], &img.data[0], width*height*4.);
```

Comment: Technically, you should check if the image is contiguous before assuming it is and copying without checking... https://stackoverflow.com/q/33665241/2836621

Comment: Mark the problem as answered.